# Django Mailsnake, apscheduler sending emails error

Tags: django, python-2.7, html-email, mandrill, apscheduler

I have a problem sending emails with mandril, I need to send an email just two days after the user has registered, this is my code:

```
bodyEmail="<p>Hey,</p><p>This is my msg</p>"
@sched.interval_schedule(hours=1)
def sendFirst():
today = datetime.datetime.now()
users = Mobile_User.objects.all().filter(emailed=False)
for i in users:
    if i.created+datetime.timedelta(hours=48) < today and i.emailed==False:
        print i.email
        try:
            mapi = MailSnakeM('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', api='mandrill')
            mapi.messages.send(message={'html':str(bodyEmail), 'subject':'first email', 'from_email':'me@me.com', 'from_name':'Adrian V', 'to':[{'email':str(i.email)}]})
            i.emailed=True
            i.save()
        except MailSnakeException:
            pass
```

The problem is after several days begins to repeatedly send the same email, sent to 2 or 3 or 4 times repeated to the same user, what am I doing wrong? any ideas? thanks

Comment: It may not necessarily be an issue with your application. Sometimes, the SMTP service provider may falsely recognize some emails as not sent, and tries resending. Check with your server administration. Another thing - if you can swtich the emails to a "Queue" based system, that way you can verify if the emails were sent __once__ or multiple times from the application server.